# htaccess rewrite and redirect to new url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

a website has url in the format:

http://domainname.com/caseshow.aspx?ivalue=engoogle**1929**

now it should redirect to:

http://domainname.com/index.php?option=com_easydiscuss&view=post&id=**1929**

i need to get last numeric digits.it can be a 2,3 or 4 digit number, and place it end of new url, i am really confused about its implementation in .htaccess

Comment: I am confused. One file extension is aspx other is php. What kind of server are You using?

Comment: Previously website was on windows server ,its has now been rebuild on Linux server using php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+caseshow\.aspx\?ivalue=[^0-9]*([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php?option=com_easydiscuss&view=post&id=%1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: it works like magic ,i need to learn that too any good tutorials links,please